# Ubuntu installation does not boot from live usb, disabling secure boot not an option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem. I wanted to install Ubuntu onto my laptop which is currently running Windows 10. Because I am not really exprienced in the field of IT, I looked at some youtube tutorials on how to exactly do this.

So I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO en put it on a live usb using 'Rufus'. So far, everything went smoothly. Then I went to advanced settings on my computer and restarted from the Live USB, which was detected without any problems. However, when the computer restarted, it went straight to Windows.

After searching on the internet I noticed that this was a common problem which could be avoided by disabling the 'secure boot'. So in BIOS I disabled the 'fast boot' but came to the conclusion that it is impossible for me to disable 'secure boot'.

Does this mean I cannot install Ubuntu on this laptop? Or are there other ways to achieve my goal?

Thanks for your reactions.

PS: I have an ASUS X75-Y086

Comment: You shouldn't have to disable secure boot to run Ubuntu, unless you later install some third-party unsigned kernel drivers. Once your dual-boot is working, you'll want to go into Windows and disable `fast startup` and `hibernation`. My experience is that Ubuntu installs work better when done from DVD. Can you burn your ISO and retry your install?

Comment: I have also experienced this issue where I would change the boot priority in the BIOS to USB first, but Windows 10 would still take over. I ended up resolving it one of two ways - disabling fast boot in Windows as heynnema suggested, or by pressing F12 during boot to access the quick boot menu (I am on a Lenovo machine, this option may not be available on your computer or use a different key, I am not sure how universal it is)

Comment: Thank you for your reactions! I will come back to you once I have made sure both hybernation and fast startup are disabled and I found the right key for quick boot menu. xD

Comment: Make sure to check your boot medium when you created it with a Windows tool. I've seen it several times that the Ubuntu installations of people acted very weirdly and after asking what they used to install it, they gave me a thumb drive I found errors on via the built-in integrity checker. You can call it by pressing the arrow up key before the boot process begins and choosing "Check installation medium for integrity". After a reinstallation with an error-free boot medium, the problems were gone. One poor guy used the faulty medium 3 times before I found the problem. Some tools mess it up.

Comment: Ok, so I tried your suggestions. Fast startup is disabled, but cant find the option to turn of hybernate anywhere. Unfortunatly, this laptop does not come with a quick boot menu so that doesnt work. UTF-8, neither can I seem to find the built-in integrity checker? Can you maybe explain in more detail, because i am starting to think it is a problem with my flash drive... I used the ISO on a VM and it seems to work there, although it freezes when i try to watch vids in youtube. Anyway, I am very thankfull for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

On my Asus I have to plug in the USB, boot to BIOS, and change the boot order, then allow the boot to proceed. If I change the boot order on a prior boot, it is not persistent, always returns to hard drive first.

If that does not work, I have also used this two pass procedure successfully on an Asus.

> > > > First Pass (disable Secure Boot)

Do not plug in the USB yet.

Restart the PC. Hold F2 for UEFI.

In the UEFI hit F7 or select Advanced Mode.

Select the Boot Menu.

Select Secure Boot.

Change the OS Type from Windows UE... to Other (the only other choice).

[image]

Exit, saving changes, and allow the boot to proceed.  It will boot to Windows.

> > > > > Second Pass (boot to USB)

Plug in the USB.

Select Restart from Windows power menu.  Hold F2 for UEFI.

On the initial UEFI screen, drag the USB to the leftmost position.  (Ensure Windows is last).

Exit the UEFI.  It will say you didn't make any changes, but it will boot to the USB.

> > > > > Restore Initial State.

Remove the USB.

Restart the PC. Hold F2 for UEFI.

In the UEFI hit F7 or select Advanced Mode.

Select the Boot Menu.

Select Secure Boot.

Change the OS Type from Other to Windows UEFI (the only other choice).

Set the Boot Order so that Windows is last. Exit, saving changes, and allow the boot to proceed.  It will boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunatly, my Bios does not have a seperate advanced settings option, so F7 doesnt work and i cannot get to the secure boot options. :(

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to an older thread in case anyone else finds this thread while encountering a similar issue.

The process to boot from a USB will vary (even across the same manufacturer) based on your laptop model.

How to get to the BIOS Setup or Boot Menu will vary. With some laptops you can press a defined key to access the BIOS setup, which I was not able to do with my laptop. My Lenovo Yoga 700 (Yoga 900 behaves similarly) has Fast Startup enabled (which I want to maintain). I power off the laptop and then press a small recessed button adjacent to the power button. Doing so powers on the laptop in a special mode and lets me choose between

1. Normal Startup
2. Bios Setup
3. Boot Menu
4. System Recovery

BIOS setup is where I would go to disable Fast Startup. As for not finding how to disable Hibernate, not all Windows 10 machines offer Hibernate as an option (I don't see it as an option in the Yoga 700 Windows Power menu whereas I do see it in the Yoga 900).

I don't need to change the BIOS settings for my purposes given what my laptop allows. I simply select Boot Menu when I want to boot from a USB.  The Boot Menu option lets me select between

1. Windows Boot Manager
2. Linpus lite (SanDisk)

Option 2 is my live USB. Selecting it then takes me to the Ubuntu menu for booting (where it lets you choose between trying Ubuntu without installing, installing Ubuntu, etc).

What the laptop needs on the USB might also vary. [For example](https://justworks.ca/blog/creating-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-for-lenovo-systems), for a Lenovo Yoga:

> The issue with booting from USB on Lenovo systems like Yoga 2 Pro,
>   Yoga 3 Pro, etc. is that they use the newer (and now fairly common)
>   UEFI instead of the old BIOS.  But they, unlike many other vendors,
>   **very specifically need to boot from a USB disk formatted with a more**
>   **obscure compatibility MBR Partition Scheme AND FAT32 file system.**

I relied on the live USB creation tutorials (and then googled information for my laptop) for which file system and partition scheme to use.

I would google how to access BIOS or boot menu, or how to boot from a USB for your specific laptop model. I found [this article](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008277/) for an ASUS.

I see that you used Rufus and that tells me that you likely don't have any persistent storage from one USB boot to the next. I am using the persistent mode [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and am loving it.